# AutoHeight IFrame

Tags: jquery, height

i want to make a iframe page that loading a page from other
site. I have try "jQuery iFrame Sizing" to set auto height in
iframe... but it is failed.

What's the problem...?

This is my code:

```
on Head:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></ script >
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iframe.js"></script >

on Body:
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1025" src="http://mydomain.com"/>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, due to browsers security limitations Javascript doesn't have the access to iframe's source that is loaded from a another domain. However there is a workaround for that, not ideal, but it works.

You can "outsmart" the browser using a simple local script that will load and output contents of mydomain.com. Then point the iframe src to this script. In that case browser will think you're dealing with the same domain and limitations won't apply.

So instead of this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1025" src="http://mydomain.com" />
```

You may try something like this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1025" src="/local-script.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com" />
```

Then you can add a simple logic into local-script.php that loads contents of domain/document you want and everything should be fine. LMK, if you need an example of PHP script.

Comment: I would make the local-script.php in this example *ONLY* accept named parameters, that will load based on a case statement server-side.  This way your script can't be used to load from "anywhere" into your pages.  Which could be problematic from a security standpoint.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing. Could you please tell me how do I display the contents of the external website in the PHP file? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not straight forward. I know that the Shindig opensocial container does something similar. Gadgets hosted in an iframe can request that the container dynamically resizes the iframe in response to changes in the gadget content inside the iframe.

The code for handling this lives in the shindig svn repo at [dynamic-height.js](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/shindig/trunk/features/src/main/javascript/features/dynamic-height/dynamic-height.js) and [dynamic-height-util.js](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/shindig/trunk/features/src/main/javascript/features/dynamic-height.util/dynamic-height-util.js).

Hopefully you can extract something usable from there.

Answer (score 0):

First two lines from [original site](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing):

> **Note**: Due to browser security
>   limitations related to cross-site
>   scripting, this solution works only
>   for iframe page content *called from the same domain*

Answer (score 0):

may be a bit late, as all the other answers are older :-) but... here´s my solution. Tested in actual FF, Chrome and Safari 5.0

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("iframe").load( function () {
        var c = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument);
        if (c.document) d = c.document;
        var ih = $(d).outerHeight();
        var iw = $(d).outerWidth();
        $(this).css({
            height: ih,
            width: iw
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this will help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

OKay my solution to set the iframe to its contents, considering you have cross access, or if not, you could maybe in your php file add this header:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

So the JS code to make the resize would be this one:

```
function resizeFrame(f) {
     var size = f.contentWindow.frameElement.clientHeight;
     f.style.height = size + "px";              
     }
```

then call resizeFrame(id reference)